# Run code to click javascript button within Android app? Trying to scrape reply button contact-info on craigslist.org page

Tags: javascript, android, html, parsing, web

I have an app I'm working on which needs to display craigslist ads. I am parsing the html to get the attributes off of the page. But herein lies the problem:

The reply button is a javascript button. In it is the email/phone# for the ad.

I need to get the info from the pane that is generated when the button is clicked and then parse its information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a callback in click event and target the affected div to probe for the content required to be parsed...

Hypothetically, lets consider a scenario...

```
<!-- CONSIDER THIS AS THE TARGET DIV WHERE CONTENT IS POPULATED-->
<div id="replydiv"></div>

<!-- BUTTON WHICH POPULATES THE DIV-->
<button id="clickme"></button>

<script>
$(function()
{
     $("#clickme").click(function()
     {
         //Will check if the div is populated 
         doCheckReply();
     })
})
</script>

 function doCheckReply()
 {
    if($("#replydiv").children().length > 0)
    {
        //start parsing 
    }
 }
```

If the replydiv is taking some time to load, use setInterval() to keep checking for availability of content.

It would help me a lot if you could share a snippet of the code

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am currently using Jsoup to pull the html from the craigslist page.


String urlString = "http://www.craigslist.org/....etc"
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new                               URL(urlString).openStream(), "ISO-8859-1", urlString);

Comment: You need to make sure where the reply button is rendered then use the selector (select("<selector path>") method) to target that element to get content. You will need to study the page source for this for craiglist

Comment: I had to get the URL the way I posted because using the defult .get() method doesn't get me the right encoding, and i'm saving the strings I parse as XML files. The .get() method was getting characters occasionally that we'rent allowable to write to XML files.

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle (for the Jsoup) if possible?

Comment: could this be the code?

<button class="reply_button js-only">reply <span class="envelope">&#9993;</span> <span class="phone">&#9742;</span></button>
    <span class="replylink"><a id="replylink" href="/reply/bli/spo/4856881912">reply</a></span>

Comment: This contains the reply button, i would need a full code to review. Anyway this looks to be the reply button you were looking for am i correct?

Comment: I have solved the issue. A second page load will be done of the link within the href of the code i posted above your last comment. That link "/reply/bli/spo...., if linked to, is the info i wanted, there to take in html form. I will just load that url and once again initiate a parse with jsoup.

Comment: I don't know if I can accept your answer, as it didn't really solve my algorithm, yet I didn't need to 'click' the button in the first place to get what I needed. thankyou for the help.